# Vuforia for Unity – Linux version

Tags: linux, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

Anyone know if Vuforia is available for the Linux version of Unity?

Can't find any valid downloads. If not - any alternatives to work with AR?

Based of this [link](https://forum.unity.com/threads/vuforia-suport-for-linux-editor.516165/), I'm guessing `No`?

Answer (score 2):

It's a pity but there's no support for Linux for Vuforia at the moment. Look at this answer of Official Vuforia Employee in [Vuforia-Unity thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/vuforia-suport-for-linux-editor.516165).

The only robust AR Development Tool I know is [ARToolKit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARToolKit). It's available as a plugin for the Unity.

Hope this helps.